# Neo4J Cypher Query to find common linked nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am making a named entity graph in Noe4j 3.2.0. I have `ARTICLE` and `ENTITY` as node types. And the relation/edge between them is `CONTAINS`; which represents the number of times the entity has occurred in that article (As shown in attached picture [Simple graph for articles and entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrnhl.png) ). So if an article has one entity for 5 times, there will be 5 edges between that article and particular entity.

There are roughly 18 million articles and 40 thousand unique entities. The whole data is around 20GB(including indices on ids) and is loaded on a machine with 32 GB RAM.

I am using this graph to suggest/recommend the other entities. But my queries are taking too much time.

Use Case1: Find all entities present in the articles which have an entity from list ["A", "B"] and also having an entity "X" and an entity "Y" and an entity "Z" in the order of articles count.

Here is the cypher query I am running.

```
MATCH(e:Entity)-[:CONTAINS]-(a:Article)
WHERE e.EID in ["A","B"]
WITH a
MATCH (:Entity {EID:"X"})-[:CONTAINS]-(a)
WITH a
MATCH (:Entity {EID:"Y"})-[:CONTAINS]-(a)
WITH a
MATCH (:Entity {EID:"Z"})-[:CONTAINS]-(a)
WITH a
MATCH (a)-[:CONTAINS]-(e2:Entity)
RETURN e2.EID as EID, e2.Text as Text, e2.Type as Type ,count(distinct(a)) as articleCount
ORDER BY articleCount desc
```

Query Profile is here: [Query Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r40GC.png)

This query gives me all first level entity neighbours of articles having X,Y,Z and at least one of A,B entities (I had to change the IDs in the query for content sensitivity).

I was just wondering if there is a better/fast way of doing it?

Another observation is if I keep adding filters (more match clauses like X,Y,Z) the performance is deteriorated; despite the fact that result set is getting smaller and smaller.

Comment: Do you actually want want **all** first level entity neighbors of `a` -- even those with `EID` values other than "A", "B", "X", "Y", and "Z"?

Comment: @cybersam Yes, EID Is unique. So A,B,X,Y,Z are search criteria. And We need to find all other entities in those articles.

Answer (score 0):

You have a uniqueness constraint on `:Entity(EID)`, so at least that optimization is already in place.

The following Cypher query is simpler, and generates a simpler execution plan. Hopefully, it also reduces the number of DB hits.

```
MATCH (e:Entity)-[:CONTAINS]-(a)
WHERE e.EID in ['A','B'] AND ALL(x IN ['X','Y','Z'] WHERE (:Entity {EID: x})-[:CONTAINS]-(a))
WITH a
MATCH (a)-[:CONTAINS]-(e2:Entity)
RETURN e2.EID as EID, e2.Text as Text, e2.Type as Type, COUNT(DISTINCT a) as articleCount
ORDER BY articleCount DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it and provide feedback.